# Android bluetooth recorder file so mall

Tags: android, bluetooth

everyone,I got a problem on bluetooth sco recorder,I'll appreciate if someone can give a advice.
I can recorder the sound on bluetooth device and save this file on android phone,but the file is so small ,always less than 10kb,it can be played,but I want it more big and clear.
here is my code:

```
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);

    mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
    mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/voice.wav";
    File file = new File(mFileName);
    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.reset();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(8);       
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        boolean isOn = mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn();
        if(isOn){
            mRecorder.start();  
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Then why are you setting your bitrate and sampling rate to such incredibly low values?

Comment: Try a sampling rate of 44100 and a bitrate of 96000.

Comment: Sorry,I have tried before,but ti is not useful,it is supposed have 100 kb

Comment: Why is the file supposed to be any particular value? Do you even know for certain there is anything wrong? I can just tell you: You need to set proper values for your audio recorder. Do you know how ridiculous a bit rate of 8 is? Do you know what bit rate means?

Comment: And if the problem is not the settings here then most likely the problem is your bluetooth device.